# Lambert_Conformal_Conic Geographic coordinate system

Tags: arcgis-engine

A shape file I am working on uses the Lambert_Conformal_Conic projection.  I would like to get a reference to this system via the IGeographicCoordinate interface.

To get at the standard lat long projection, I do this

IGeographicCoordinate gcs = srFactory.CreateGeographicCoordinateSystem((int)esriSRGeoCSType.esriSRGeoCS_WGS1984);

So I looked for lambert in the enum type of esriSRGeoCSType but couldn't find anything close. Does anyone know what I'm missing?

I'm using ArcEngine 10 in VS2010 with C#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [esriSpatialReferenceProjection.ImportFromESRISpatialReference](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//002m000001n2000000) and add the [projection](http://forums.esri.com/Thread.asp?c=93&f=993&t=105038) .

PROJCS["NAD_1983_Quebec_Lambert",GEOGCS["GCS_North_American_1983",DATUM["D_North_American_1983",SPHEROID["GRS_1980",6378137,298.257222101]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199432955]],PROJECTION["Lambert_Conformal_Conic"],PARAMETER["False_Easting",0],PARAMETER["False_Northing",0],PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",-68.5],PARAMETER["Standard_Parallel_1",46],PARAMETER["Standard_Parallel_2",60],PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin",44],UNIT["Meter",1]]